# Progress 4GL - App Server adapter Not Running

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

How to run the app server adapter?

We are trying to deploy a Progress OpenEdge 11.5 based web service on Windows 10. We need to run the **App Server Adapter**, but inside **Openedge Progress** Explorer, it is showing as:

> not running.

We followed some steps given in the Progress Knowledgebase article: [knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P150680](https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P150680) to no avail.

The log file shows:

```
[19/11/22@12:50:33.510+0530] P-000000 T-localhost-startStop-1 1 --- --- C:\OpenEdgex86\WRK\wsa1.wsa.log opened.
[19/11/22@12:50:33.511+0530] P-000000 T-localhost-startStop-1 1 --- --- Logging level set to = 2
[19/11/22@12:50:33.511+0530] P-000000 T-localhost-startStop-1 1 --- --- Log entry types activated: WSADefault,
[19/11/22@12:50:33.518+0530] P-000000 T-localhost-startStop-1 3 wsa1 WSA Starting WSA adapter wsa1, version 11.5, ID 2ca03e8111bdce1c:2073cee4:16e91fbdf32:-7fff (10620)
```

Comment: It would be helpful to know what steps you followed.  Not everyone knows which existing Q&As you might have found.  It would also be useful to know what OS you are working with and what version of Progress/OpenEdge this situation relates to.  There should also be log files in your WRKDIR that could, perhaps, shine some light on the issue.  You might want to share the last few lines of those logs.

Comment: Steps are followed as per the page - https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P150680?popup=true, OS - Windows - 10, Progress/OpenEdge version - 11.5

Comment: logs -[19/11/22@12:50:33.510+0530] P-000000 T-localhost-startStop-1 1 --- --- C:\OpenEdgex86\WRK\wsa1.wsa.log opened.
[19/11/22@12:50:33.511+0530] P-000000 T-localhost-startStop-1 1 --- --- Logging level set to = 2
[19/11/22@12:50:33.511+0530] P-000000 T-localhost-startStop-1 1 --- --- Log entry types activated: WSADefault,
[19/11/22@12:50:33.518+0530] P-000000 T-localhost-startStop-1 3 wsa1 WSA              Starting WSA adapter wsa1, version 11.5, ID 2ca03e8111bdce1c:2073cee4:16e91fbdf32:-7fff (10620)

Comment: Is the admin service running?  You can easily check from a PROENV command line:  proenv>  proadsv -query